# Open file and use toupper

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment for school that needs me to open a file name and then reprint it making everything upper case.  I get multiple errors when trying to compile varying from "function does not take arguments", to "char is incompatible with type int" and "fileName undeclared identifier" to name a few.  I have been searching the internet and my C programming book for hours and I am just not understanding.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main()
{

    FILE *inFile;
    char *fileName[20];



    printf("Enter a file name: ");
    fgets(*fileName);
    inFile = fopen_s(*fileName, "r");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe file %s was not successfully opened.", *fileName);
        printf("\nPlease check that the file currently exists.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nThe file has been successfully opened for reading.\n");

    printf("\n%fileName", toupper(*fileName));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *fileName[20];` what is this supposed to do? An array of 20 character pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are too many errors. You should learn how to use these functions.

This fixed code at least compiles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* include this to use strchr */
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{

    FILE *inFile;
    char fileName[20];
    char *lf;

    printf("Enter a file name: ");
    fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);
    if ((lf = strchr(fileName, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0'; /* remove newline character after the string */
    inFile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe file %s was not successfully opened.", fileName);
        printf("\nPlease check that the file currently exists.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nThe file has been successfully opened for reading.\n");

    printf("\n%cfileName", toupper((unsigned char)*fileName));
    fclose(inFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Change

   `char *fileName[20];`

to

```
   char fileName[20];
```

2. Read about the [proper use of fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)
3. Read the manual page for `toupper` as well

....

In fact when using something it is a good idea to read the manual instead of hoping for the best

Comment: Read manual of `fopen_s`, too.